# Llamar un método desde un form (html)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, webforms

Tengo un `form` donde introduzco varios parámetros y quiero guardarlos en una *base de datos* (SQL). Para ello, creé un método pero no sé cómo llamarlo desde el `form`.

```
<form class="input-data" action="MetodoNuevaPetición" runat="server">
<div id="titulo">
<input type="text" id="inputTitulo">
</div>
<div id="explicación">
<input type="explicación" id="inputExplicación">
</div>
<button id="btn" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Estoy utilizando un **Web Form** de *Visual Studio*, tengo el `form` en el *archivo.aspx* y el método en el *archivo.aspx.cs*

Comment: creo que estas interiorizandote en este tema de asp.net webforms, te recomendaria ir por el lado de ASP.NET MVC? y mejor si es ASP.NET Core MVC Dale una mirada simple comenzando con pequeños ejemplos. [Para comenzar mira aqui](https://www.asp.net/get-started)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba revisando este ***[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d00e25ec-9469-447b-b50b-9e2d42643bcc/como-ejecutar-un-metodo-de-un-formulario-form1-desde-otro-formulario-form2?forum=esdevwindows)*** donde puede aclararte las dudas que te surgen con lo que preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que profundizar el tema de ciclo de vida de una pagina en webforms, asi podras visualizar como se "mueven los datos" o mejor dicho los eventos.

- [Información general sobre el ciclo de vida de una página ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

En tu caso particular, como hacer que un evento click del boton envie los datos del formulario nuevamente al servidor, al codebehind del formulario
Para eso te puede ayudar este enlace

- [Creating a Basic ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Page in Visual Studio 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page)

Pero esta parte es solamente para enviar desde el clietne al servidor. Luego la otra parte es "acceder a datos de la base de datos". Y aqui es otro tema. 
TE recomiendo comenzar por estos dos lugares

- [ASP.NET WebForms > Presenting and Managing Data](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data)
- [ASP.NET Webforms > Data controls](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls)

Pero aqui en acceso a datos o comienzas

El sitio oficial de ASP.NET Webforms tambien te puede ayudar de guia donde estan separados por area de acceso datos, validacion, autenticacion, autorizacion, etc
 - [ASP.NET Webforms overview](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia